# Local variables within smart contracts (Smartpy)

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'd like to share a question that were being worked on Smartpy telegram, and also a few thoughts along the way (it's a long way -- random observation).

Some people were talking about [local variables](https://smartpy.io/demo/reference.html#_local_variables) and in the meanwhile I was working in a smart contract in which I'd like to insert a list within a map -- also retrieve it, modify it, etc.

The only way I reached it was by declaring a list in the storage of the smart contract. Part of this question concerns some typos.

Previous solution:

```
    self.init(
            map_example = sp.big_map(tkey=sp.TInt, tvalue=sp.TList(t=sp.TInt)),
            aux_list = sp.list(t=sp.TInt)
    )


    @sp.entry_point
    def initialize(self, params):
        sp.for i in sp.range(1, 3):
            self.data.aux_list = []
            sp.for k in sp.range(0, 8):
                self.data.aux_list.push(k)
            self.data.map_example[i] = self.data.aux_list

...
```

With this typo it was possible to execute the procedure in mind. But how to insert a list within the map with a local list?

I tryied:

```
        sp.for i in sp.range(1, 3):
            aux_list = []
            sp.for k in sp.range(0, 8):
                aux_list.append(k)  #  .push(k)
            self.data.map_example[i] = aux_list
```

With the help of @FFF ? (on telegram), we got to this example, which is interesting to observe the typo so you can handle local variables (notice the value? method/attribute).

```
    sp.for i in sp.range(1, 3):
        aux_list = sp.local('aux_list', [])
        sp.for k in sp.range(0, 8):
            aux_list.value.push(k)
        self.data.map_example[i] = aux_list.value
```

Finally, a cleaner way to write it:

```
sp.for i in sp.range(1, 3):
    self.data.map_example[i] = sp.range(0, 8)
```

If someone has something to add, be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a precision: `sp.range` is computed on chain while simply `range` is computed at compile time.

For a small range, it's probably much cheaper to use `range` (cheaper in terms of gas + storage).